# How to Make a PDF from View in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I am trying to make a pdf from a view using DOMPDF and wrote following code

```
Route::get('/pdf',function() {
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('pages.about');
return $pdf->stream();
});
```

but getting this error

[image]

Comment: Create `fonts` directory in `storage` folder, it should fix Your problem.

Comment: Something weird is happening when it's trying to load the font. It starts out with forward slashes until it gets to the fonts directory then starts using backslashes. I'd check how you're loading fonts and see how the path is set up there.

Comment: Directory separator differences have caused problems in the past and that *could* be a problem for you. Try [updating to dompdf 0.7.0](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.7.0) to see if that fixes your problems. But honestly it looks more like dompdf does not have read/write access to the font directory. You'll either need to give it access or set a different font directory.